# Deadpool doesn't work with gamepad

Tags: pc, controllers, deadpool

I recently installed deadpool and I enjoy it very much. But playing with the keyboard is more distracting and less fun than playing with the gamepad. I tried using a wireless gamepad and the X-Axis of DPad is inverted. I tried installing Xpadder but it didn't work.

What can I do to get the gamepad working ? Or, if I can't, Can I emulate keyboard strokes with the gamepad through key mappings ?

Comment: You may want to mention what gamepad you have.

Answer (score 2):

OK, solved.
I didn't know the deadpool game **also** worked with Xbox 360 controllers, so instead of looking for a keyboard emulation (which is very difficuly to find, to my experience, with nothing satisfying), I used an XInput (the branch of DirectX responsible for input) remapper.

[X360ce](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce) worked for me. It even found default key mappings for my controller. All I needed to do was to launch the gui application and hit save. Then, copy the xinput1_3.dll and x360ce.ini files to the game's Binary folder and it works just fine now !